# get jQuery variable in php from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, date

I have a loop on my archive-tour page in which I output dates of on week after then the selected date.

```
<ul class="uol">
    <?php
    $start = strtotime($_GET['date']);
    $dates = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day", $start));
        $date1 = $date;
        $day = date('D', strtotime($date1));
        $date = explode('-', $date);
        $dateinput = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day", $start));
        $date = $date[2];

        echo '<li class="lia"><input type="hidden" class="getdate"    value="'.$dateinput.'"><a href="#tabs-0" class="date">' . $date . '  ' . $day . '</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
    <li class="lia" style="background-color:blue"><a style="background-   color:blue" href="#tabs-0" class="date tdate"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here i have another loop on buttons as seen below.
1:00 am - 2:00 am......

```
<button type="button" style="background-color:blue" id="ttime<?php echo  $post->ID?>" class="btn btn-default time-pick tt_time" value=""></button>
for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
    am = "";
    if ($i <= 12) {
        $am = "am"; 
    } else {
        $am = "pm";
    }
    echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">' . $i.':00 ' . $am . ' - ' . ++$i .':00 '. $am . '</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    --$i;
}
```

Now user can select date and according time to book tour.
i am getting the selected time and date and i want to highlight the above date and time accordingly. currently setting time and date outer then the loop. but i want to match date with selected date, if it present then highlight it and same for the time. for example in user selects 9:00 am - 10:00 am then my code add one more button with this time. i want to highlight the existing when by applying a if condition in loop that if date=selcted_date then highlight that one.

```
jQuery('#time<?php echo $post->ID?>').html(t_time); 
$(".tdate").html(date);
```

how can i send the jquery variable t_time from footer page to archive page and get it on archive page in php so that i can use it in if condition.
Remember its is wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can use `localStorage`.

```
localStorage.setItem('t_time','Your setTime' ); //set your value
```

And to get

```
localStorage.getItem('t_time'); //Get your value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's `$.post()` as follows..

```
   var ttime =  jQuery('#time<?php echo $post->ID?>').html(); 
     $.post('php_file_name.php',{'ttime':ttime},function(data,status){
       });
```

And in your php file..

```
$time = $_POST['ttime'];//get ttime send from jquery
//echo $time
```